# perl 101 - "@" for arrays or hashes

Tags: perl

```
 foreach (@v) { s/^\s+//; s/\s+$// }
        push @{$data[$x]}, @v;
      }
```

I'm getting an error : global variable @data requires explicit package name – 
Not sure how to add "my" to it.

But I also don't understand this line of code,

- It's pushing the v element into data[x]. But how does the @ work. I understand the {} is used for hash.

Comment: Usually that "explicit package required" error comes from mistyping a variable name, so it doesn't match the variable you declared earlier with `my`.

Comment: Post a complete, valid program. That snippet doesn't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) declares lexically-scoped variables.  It doesn't seem appropriate here, since there appear to be no new variables being named, unless `@data` is new, in which case the `my` must move:

```
push @{(my @data)[$x]}, @v;
```

which is mostly useless as the lexical scope of `@data` disappears immediately, or more clearly and usefully:

```
my @data;
push @{$data[$x]}, @v;
```

where `@data` is in a slightly larger scope.

---

[`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) explains `@{...}`.  Without `my`,

```
push @{$data[$x]}, @v;
```

means to take the `$x`th element of the `@data` array, treat it as an array reference, and append `@v` to it.

For example,

```
my @data = (
    [],          # 0
    ['a'],       # 1
    ['b'],       # 2
    ['c', 'd'],  # 3
);
my $x = 2;
my @v = ('e', 'f');

push @{$data[$x]}, @v;
# @data = (
#     [],               # 0
#     ['a'],            # 1
#     ['b', 'e', 'f'],  # 2
#     ['c', 'd'],       # 3
# );
```

Comment: Thanks so much ephemient
just saw your answer...:)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to define `@data` at the same time you're pushing into it? It's unclear as to what that `my` is for without more information.

The `@{}` wrapper says "the thing inside the braces is an arrayref, so treat it as a real array now". The push command should copy all the elements of the `@v` array onto the `$x`'th element of the `@data` array, which should be an array reference.

Comment: yeah exactly, it's defining and pushing at the same time

Comment: I'm getting global variable  @data requires explicit package name

Comment: Any particular reason you can't just prefix this line with `my @data`? This assumes that `$x` and `@v` are already defined, of course.  I don't think you can target the `@data` variable directly for `my` definition while in that big mess of `@{$data[$x]}` :)

Comment: ok thx, yeah just added an extra line